# Merge items on Hibernate collection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AA_CHARGE")
public class Charge2 extends AbstractProduct implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String currency;

    private String chargeType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "charge")
    private Set<Rate2> chargeRates;

    ...
}

public class Rate2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="RATE_ID")
    private String id;

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

    private BigDecimal rate;

    private String templateType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="CHARGE_ID")
    private Charge2 charge;

    ...
}
```

I am have a specified **Charge object** with only a element on **chargeRates collection** (for example with id A) and this is saved on database.

After this situation, i read another object and get the same charge but the **chargeRates collection are not equals**. (for example have a rate with id B).

Should hibernate update my Charge and put 2 elements in the chargeRates?
After this, if i make a query on database i got an error "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with session"

The charge id is the same, why hibernate give this error for this situation? thanks

Answer (score 1):

No Hibernate will not update your existing charge object. Because you did not updated the existing charge object which is already attached with the hibernate session. As you created new charge object hibernate don't know whether it's content is similar to the one that already attached because, **the hash codes of the two objects are not same.** As a result you got the exception.

**Solution:**

When you see that the second object is similar to the prior object. You can only add the new chargeRate object to the list of the previous charge object. And then update the object (the change is reflected in the database).

Comment: I dont create a new charge object, is an object with the same id. if i got the equals method with id, hibernate must detect which it's the same object

Comment: No. If you only override equal method, hibernate will never be able to detect the object. You also need to override the hashcode method, becasue session internally uses hashing to store and track object. So objects with different hashcode goes to different locations and only overriding equal method creates nothing but inconsistency.

Comment: i had hashcode and equals. but my class extends an abstract class and i have to check if my abstract have that methods